# Springsource git creates nested folders

Tags: git, github, springsource

I'm new to Spring Source and git and I'm having issues sharing a project.

These are the steps I am following to share the project to git after creating a Spring MVC project:
Create a new repository named MyProject

When it creates that project, it does so with a nested project named:
".../github/MyProject/MyProject"

When I push that to git, it creates a folder 'MyProject' on git and places all the src etc under that.  I've noticed that this behavior is not the normal layout for projects I have browsed.

Am I doing something wrong in any of these steps?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific here.  How are you creating the project? STS? Command line? What tool are you using to push to git? Egit? Command line?